# I don't understand how to use document.getElementById(‘id’).onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning javascript right now and I am just building a simple menu that will show when the nav button is clicked.

I don't understand how to use the document.getElementById(‘id’).onclick when in a separated js file that is linked to my html. Reading around I think I understand that my problem is that you cannot call onclick out the blue because the DOM element are not yet defined.. or something alone those line. I just don't understand then how to proceed.

If I add within my button html tag onclick="function()" it works, but it don't when I add it within my separate js file. I'm using the W3school tutorial found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown).

Here is my code

```
<nav>
      <button class="nav-button" id="nav">
        <div class="menu-button"></div>
        <div class="menu-button"></div>
        <div class="menu-button"></div>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

.nav-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-button {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.showDropDown {
  display: block;
}


function showDropDown() {
  document.getElementById('dropdown').classList.toggle("showDropDown");
}

document.getElementById("nav").onclick = function showDropDown()
```

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/oehaut/pen/zzJQqz)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That JavaScript code posted is not even valid syntax - read the error log / console for help fixing trivial mistakes which may also just lead to..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just instead of

```
document.getElementById("nav").onclick = function showDropDown()
```

replace it with

```
document.getElementById("nav").onclick = showDropDown
```

because the onclick accepts function and you'r already defined this function

Comment: Wow, newbie mistake, that indeed did it! If I may ask, why is not = showDropDown(), since I am pointing to a function?

Comment: @oehaut `showDropDown()` will *execute* the function named by `showDropDown`. Thus, `..onclick = showDropDown()` really is `..onclick = {the result of calling the function}`. Unless the function *returns a function* to be used as the callback, which it does not, this is not very useful. The *practical* observation of `..onclick = showDropDown()` will thus be something like "showDropDown is called once on loading and never when the button is clicked".

Comment: @oehaut http://eloquentjavascript.net/ a good resource to learn about functions in JavaScript. It also contains a number of practical hands-on examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

1.create myjavascript.js file in same folder where your page html is.

2.copy the javascript code in myjavascript.js "only code not tag `<script></script>`"

4.paste this at the end of your html page

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" src="myjavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
```

This is the way to reference your code javascript in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier to work with jquery than plain javascript. 
Here how you are calling showDropDown function  is wrong

> `change function showDropDown` to
>   `showDropDown`

Better you can make the closure at the button click event like

```
let btn = document.getElementById("nav"); 
let toggleIt = document.getElementById('dropdown'); 
btn.onclick = function(){  
toggleIt.classList.toggle("showDropDown"); 
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Having it in a separate js file should work you just need to import the js file using the script tag. You should probably do this at the end of the HTML to guarantee that the js is ran after the DOM is loaded.

*Update* Your missing the brackets around the function call:

document.getElementById("nav").onclick = function() { showDropDown(); };

Comment: I'm having this <script src="test.js"></script> in my header. The js file is working since I can call my function just fine when i do <button onclick="showDropDown()"

I tried adding it at the end of the html but it's not working.

Comment: your missing the brackets around the function call when you set it to the onclick property. see below.

document.getElementById("nav").onclick = function() { showDropDown(); };